# InBox not working after re-install the app

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios, inbox

InBox not working after re-install the app on the same device.
So, in that case Contact will have 2 devices.

Steps:

1. List item
2. Install app.
3. Set Contact Key.
4. Verify that InBox messages delivered.
5. Delete the app.
6. Install the app again.
7. Use the same Contact Key from Step #2.
8. InBox messages stop working.

We tried to find different workarounds, but only 1 option is working - request Push Notifications permissions. If users accept it - the InBox became alive.
We are using MobilePush SDK 6.4.2.

How to setup MobilePush iOS SDK correct way to avoid issue during re-install the app?

Answer (score 0):

we are having similar issue.

For us we had to create a new fresh distribution list again (with the same contact key) and send the push+inbox to this new list, by doing so we were able to see the inbox showing the new messages.

However previous messages for the same user are lost since the SDK will create a new DeviceID after reinstalling the App and the SDK will try to fetch messages for this new Device ID.

This is inconvenient for us since the user could potentially lose all records and seems there is nothing to work around this.